# playTogether(Animator...) is not applicable for the arguments (ObjectAnimator, ObjectAnimator)

Tags: android, animation, objectanimator

Eclipse won't let me compile my project because of this error:

```
The method playTogether(Animator...) in the type AnimatorSet is not applicable for the arguments (ObjectAnimator, ObjectAnimator, ObjectAnimator)
```

Here is a snippet of code illustrating the problem:

```
AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();             
//IMPORTED NINEOLDANDROID LIBRARY TO HANDLE THIS PRE-HONEYCOMB
           ObjectAnimator colorAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(findViewById(v.getId()), "backgroundColor", colorFrom, colorTo);
           colorAnimation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
           //colorAnimation.start();

           ObjectAnimator txtColor = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(txtDesc, "textColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.bg), getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
           txtColor.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
           //txtColor.start();

           ObjectAnimator txtAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(txtDesc, "backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.white), colorTo);
           txtAnimation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
           //txtAnimation.start();

           s.playTogether(colorAnimation, txtColor, txtAnimation);

            s.setDuration(250).start();
```

Essentially what I'm doing is when a user touches the screen I want to change the colour of a number of views.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can offer.

Comment: Any chance the `AnimatorSet` is not imported from NineOldAndroids, but rather the standard SDK?

Comment: Jake Wharton's primary example on the NineOldAndroids website make use of it...

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: make sure all your imports point to `com.nineoldandroids.animation.*` and that you're not mixing it up with any of the `android.animation.*` classes...

Comment: You're right, I had both the standard android.animation.* import and the nineoldandroids import.That was obviously causing Eclipse to become confused. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had both the standard android.animation.* import and the nineoldandroids import.That was obviously causing Eclipse to become confused.